# Can I import a Solidworks model into Blender and animate a folding piece of cloth?

Tags: rendering, animation, materials, cloth-simulation

It's basically a travel cot, so I have the full model in Solidworks, but I would like to get an animation of the fabric folding with the cot if possible? (I'm new to blender!)